# How are deletes handled in larger databases?

Tags: database

I'm writing a simple database, and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to delete records.

The simplest database I can think of is simply a file in a file system.

Inserts could be performed as

```sh
% echo "1 hello" >> db.txt
```

And finds are performed with

```sh
% grep 1 db.txt
1 hello
```

And boom we have a database.

The only way I can think of deleting a record from this database is to copy the whole database to a new file, removing the unwanted record, and rename the new file to `db.txt`, removing the old file.

This seems very wasteful, and requires loading the whole database into memory, and generally seems very messy. But, of course, deletion is a nice function to have within a database. I have a hard time believing that databases with large amounts of information re-write themselves every time someone wants to delete a record. So, how do databases perform deletions efficiently? Is the database split among multiple, smaller, files and only one of those has to be rewritten on a delete?

Note: I mean actually deleting a file from the database, rather than say adding a "deleted" field and ignoring those records with queries.

Comment: It varies, but quite often it is done precisely by changing a marker byte from "currently active record" to "logically deleted record".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so like does a database ever get smaller? Do the logically deleted records ever actually get deleted? Is having a database on your system going to grow until it maxes out your hard drive no matter what?

Comment: It varies, as always, but — quite often a database file won’t shrink during normal operation, but only when some special operation is done. But typically a deleted record would be reused before extending the file.